# Predefining requirements before starting a controller object. Is it called DI container?

Tags: php

I've been using registry pattern for a very long time. Basically, I load all the classes using a main object (even if they're not required by the controller itself) and controllers can reach them.

It loads like 20 classes currently and I want to change my approach.

I want to define dependencies for my controllers. For example, my register controller only depends on database class, recaptcha class and filter class.

So, I want to create a solution like this:

```
//dependencies 
$registerDependencies = array(new Database(), new Recatpcha(), new Filter());

//load register controller
$this->loadController->('register', $this->loadDependencies($registerDependencies));
```

Is it called DI/DI Container? 
Is this a better approach than my current system?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use this approach:

```
$this->loadController->register('database.main', 'Database')
                     ->register('database.user', 'Database')
                     ->register('recaptcha', 'Racatpcha');
```

And the register function would look like this

```
public function register($serviceName, $serviceClass)
{
    // you can inject options to your class via a config array or a conf file
    $this->registry[$serviceName] = new $serviceClass();
}
```

If you give an alias to your service, you could have multiple services that share the same class but with different parameters.
The service 'database.main' could connect to a DB and 'database.user' to another DB.

Symfony2 uses dependency injection and you can find [documentation about the component on their website](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dependency_injection/introduction.html).

Comment: What is this approach called as? DI or DI Container, or none of them?